# iOS 7- MKCircleRenderer Not Being Drawn?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mkmapview

Been trying to figure this out for hours. Trying to do something simple: draw a circle overlay on mapview. BLEvent conforms to the MKMapOverLay protocol and has the information needed (radius, coordinates) Yes my view controller has been set as the map view delegate.

In my viewDidLoad..

```
 for (BLEvent *event in self.model.events) {
        [self.mapView addOverlay:event];
    }


- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay{

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[BLEvent class]]){
        BLEvent *event = (BLEvent *)overlay;

        MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:event.coordinate radius:event.radius];
        MKCircleRenderer *circleR = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:circle];
        circleR.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];


        return circleR;
    } else{
        return nil;
    }
}
```

I checked with this, and the renderer was in fact called> I know the coordinates are valid because I had annotations that showed in the map.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didAddOverlayRenderers:(NSArray *)renderers{
    NSLog(@"%@", ((MKCircleRenderer *)[renderers objectAtIndex:0]).fillColor);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The circle is not drawn because the MKCircle you create is not added as overlay to the map.

In order to make this work your BLEvent class needs to be a MKCircle subclass.

Then try this:

```
- (MKOverlayRenderer *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView rendererForOverlay:(id < MKOverlay >)overlay{

    if ([overlay isKindOfClass:[BLEvent class]]){
        BLEvent *event = (BLEvent *)overlay;

        MKCircleRenderer *circleR = [[MKCircleRenderer alloc] initWithCircle:event];
        circleR.fillColor = [UIColor blueColor];

        return circleR;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A working version for iOS 8.0 and SWIFT

```
import Foundation
import MapKit

class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate{
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager = CLLocationManager()

    @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // We use a predefined location
        var location = CLLocation(latitude: 46.7667 as CLLocationDegrees, longitude: 23.58 as CLLocationDegrees)

        addRadiusCircle(location)
    }

    func addRadiusCircle(location: CLLocation){
        self.mapView.delegate = self
        var circle = MKCircle(centerCoordinate: location.coordinate, radius: 10000 as CLLocationDistance)
        self.mapView.addOverlay(circle)
    }

    func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
        if overlay is MKCircle {
            var circle = MKCircleRenderer(overlay: overlay)
            circle.strokeColor = UIColor.redColor()
            circle.fillColor = UIColor(red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.1)
            circle.lineWidth = 1
            return circle
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```